# fluidcontent "Template could not be loaded."

Tags: typo3, tx-fluidcontent

I upgraded my TYPO3 version from 6.2 to 7.6.27. Accordingly, the extension *[fluidcontent](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fluidcontent/)* to 5.2.0

Now I get the following error message in the frontend:

> Template could not be loaded.

I tried `/Content/Render.html`, `/Content/render.html`

In the `ext_localconf.php` is the following in it:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        'FluidTYPO3.Fluidcontent',
        'Content',
        [
            'Content' => 'render',
        ],
        [],
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT
    );
```

I look now in the appropriate folder. Is not `render.html` or `Render.html` in it. If I create both consecutively, I still get the error message. Cache has been emptied.

Now I do not know any more advice.
Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd suggest moving on to *at least* TYPO3 8.7, since TYPO3 7.6 will only have security- and bugfixes until October 2018 where TYPO3 8.7 will have them until March 2020.

Second I am guessing, based on the given details in your question, that your files are not properly located. Did you make sure they are based on MVC? So the requested 'Render.html' should be found at:

```
typo3conf/ext/your_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Render.html
```

**Edit:**
If it's not your own extension (thanks for the markup-edit), did you include the extension configuration into the template? This can be done via editing the template inside the TYPO3 backend, select "*edit whole template*" and selecting the configuration of 'fluidcontent' at the *Includes*-tab.

Comment: additonally be aware that if you are using a templateRootPath setting in your TypoScript settings file , that the naming had changed from templateRootPath to templateRootPaths and it is now an array!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have the correct pathes configured, also have the correct spelling of your templates (leading uppercase)

Do you have configured `path`or `paths`?
Do you use `constants` or `setup`?

What folder have you configured as base folder for templates?

Specify it in your question adding a screenshot showing the typoscript setup (TSOB).
[this](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/file-structure.html) should be the documentation
and this the typoscript in question (copied from that page):

```
plugin.tx_myextensionkey.view {
    templateRootPath = EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPath = EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPath = EXT:myextensionkey/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}
```

Comment: I use path.

I didn't use contants or setup.

I added the file, but the error remains. i.stack.imgur.com/YsHkO.png

Comment: more intersting than the path where your template is stored is the typoscript you use and where and in which way the path is configured (`plugin.myext.view.templateRootPath` or similar)

Comment: I finally found a solution.

I have the extension "fluidcontent_bootstrap" installed and activated. Bug fixed.